# Oracle Tablespace Predictive alert and template not giving proper result

Tags: oracle, bosun

I am quite new to Bosun and have been trying to configure predictive alerts for tablespace usage. I will paste my template and alert code

```
template predict_diskspace {
body = `{{template "header" .}}
<p>Host: <a href="{{.HostView .Group.host | short }}">{{.Group.host}}</a>
#<br>Disk: {{.Group.disk}}

<p>Free Space: {{.Eval .Alert.Vars.free_space | printf "%.2f"}}%
<br>Used: {{.Eval .Alert.Vars.used | bytes}}
<br>Total: {{.Eval .Alert.Vars.total | bytes}}
<br>Est. {{.Eval .Alert.Vars.days_to_full | printf "%.2f"}} days remain until 0% free space
{{/* .Graph .Alert.Vars.percent_free_graph */}}
`
subject = {{.Last.Status}}: Oracle Tablespace: ({{.Alert.Vars.used | .Eval | bytes}}/{{.Alert.Vars.total | .Eval | bytes}}) {{.Alert.Vars.free_space | .Eval | printf "%.2f"}}% (Est. {{.Eval .Alert.Vars.days_to_full | printf "%.2f"}} days remain)
```

}

```
alert predict_orcl_tbs {
$notes = This alert triggers when there are issues detected in Oracle tablespace free space (hopefully).
template=predict_diskspace
$filter=host=testhost,tablespace_name=*,oracle_database=*

## Forecast Section
$days_to_full=(forecastlr(q("sum:6h-avg:oracle.tablespace_usage{$filter}", "7d", ""), 0) / 60 / 60 / 24)
$warn_days = $days_to_full > 0 && $days_to_full < 7
$crit_days = $days_to_full > 0 && $days_to_full < 1

##Percent Free Section
$pf_time = "5m"
$used =  avg(q("max:oracle.tablespace_usage{$filter}", $pf_time, ""))
$total = avg(q("sum:oracle.tablespace_usage{$filter}", $pf_time, ""))
$free_space = $total - $used

# For Graph
$percent_free_graph = q("avg:1h-min:oracle.tablespace_usage{$filter}", "4d", "")

warn = $warn_days
crit = $crit_days
```

}

I am expecting that the result it should give as in how many days will my tablespace usage will be 100% full.

But the output is a bit weird and I am not sure what the issue is. Sample output from the template is

"
Subject
normal: Oracle Tablespace: (NaNB/NaNB) NaN% (Est. -3650.00 days remain)
Body

Acknowledge alert

View the Rule + Template in the Bosun's Rule Page

Notes: This alert triggers when there are issues detected in Oracle tablespace free space.

View Host dba in Opserver

Host: testhost #
Disk:

Free Space: NaN%
Used: NaNB
Total: NaNB
Est. -3650.00 days remain until 0% free space
"
The values of Est. days remain, Free space, Used, Total are coming wrong. Can someone help me in correcting the alert?

Thanks

Comment: What does the time series data look like for the result that is creating the NaN? I.e. roughly how many observations, and if there are observations, do they all have the same value?